# How to build OpenCV for PNaCl on Windows

Tags: javascript, c++, opencv, web-applications, google-nativeclient

I'm beginner to PNaCl/NaCl and have a problem.
I want to use "openCV" on Web Native Client. So I tried to build "naclports" on cygwin.
But it was failed..
below is my workflow and result. Please tell me what is wrong or alternative idea to use "openCV".
*I use windows8.1 and cygwin.

```
1. Download and install the [Native Client SDK][1].
     - installed pepper version is 35. PATH is C:/cygwin64/home/*user*/nacl_sdk/pepper_35 (set the environment variable).

2. Clone the "[naclports][2]" in  C:/cygwin64/home/*user*/naclports/src/

3. Done the build on cygwin.
**@** ~/naclports/src
$make opencv

4. error is coming:
######################################################################
Testing zlib
######################################################################
chdir /home/ryosuke/naclports/src/out/build/zlib/zlib-1.2.8
DEBUG MODE ENABLED (bypass acl)
fread: Broken pipe
DEBUG MODE ENABLED (bypass acl)
NaClMain: <fd:0>: Broken pipe
  *** minigzip test FAILED ***
naclports: Building 'zlib' failed.
Makefile:68: recipe for target 'opencv' failed
make: *** [opencv] Error 1
```

Do you have any good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately many of the ports in naclports don't currently building cygwin.  In this case you can see that its actually zlib that is failing to build.

If possible you can build the ports a mac or linux machine and copy the resulting packages over.

A system for installing binary package is currently being developed to make it easier to install pre-built packages rather than building them from source.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, sbc.
I have tried building in Ubuntu in Virtualbox, and it works fine!